# How to solve an interesting Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, computational-complexity

During a complexity analysis of an algorithm, I came upon the following series:

For some $M$

$T_d(1) = m$

$T_0(n) = m$

$T_d(n) = m + T_{d-1}(n-1) + T_d(n-1)$

I would love some help solving this

Comment: The recurrence is not really readable. Is T a sequence/matrix with 2 indexes/dimensions?

Comment: Why would that be "interesting"?

Comment: Yes there’s 2 dimensions sorry for the confusing notation.

Comment: It’s interesting since it represents the complexity of a parity game solver.

Comment: Just by intuitive expansion: I got mn^d, and I can prove this by simple induction. thank you